Generating pseudo-random sample sequence with a given autocorrelation function up to max lag
Assume the variable $X_t$ has a continuous value, sampled over uniform discrete time (time series).

I have the full autocorrelation function up to max time lag $l_{max}$. The coefficients may be both positive and negative. Some coefficients may be zero.
I have the full time series "history", $X_0$ to $X_t$ necessary to satisfy any initial lag conditions during the beginning of the sequence generation. I'd like to generate any number of random possible sequence extensions $X_{t+1}$ to $X_{t+N}$, where the extension sequence fully honors (or at least converges on, with some reasonable tolerance) all autocorrelation coefficients of the historical period up to max time lag $l_{max}$.
The distribution of the data is complex and multimodal, so I would prefer a non-parametric method, if possible, however I realize this could further complicate things. So if a non-parametric technique is too difficult, I am willing to compromise with sampling from a loosely fitting gaussian distribution. Or if it would simplify things, we could also assume I have a KDE estimate of the distribution available to sample from: ${\widehat {f}}_{h}(X)$

Any ideas or algorithms are welcome, including iterative techniques. Thanks in advance.

Does it matter that $X_t$ is continuous if it is sampled over uniform discrete time? If not, I think you could try simulating from a moving average (MA) model, since this model can be defined by its autocorrelations. If you have $l_{max}$ of them, it would be an MA($l_{max}$) model.

Did you have a look at block bootstrap?
Block bootstrap assumes you have a sample of the random process $X_t$ (which obviously has the autocorrelation you seek, then you can just resample (draw with replacement) blocks of a length longer than the maximal autocorrelation you are interested. The resulting resamples should have an estimated autocorrelation very close to the one you have in your original sample.

This is an interesting proposal, but is there any scheme to "transition" the blocks in a seamless fashion? Remember $X_t$ is a continuous value, so just piecewise concatenation of random blocks in themselves would tend to cause obvious and abrupt jumps.

I think people introduced smooth block bootstrap versions

Could you please edit your answer to provide a reference to the "smooth block bootstrap"? If there are also other variations, it might be nice to also mention the more popular ones.
